# Select objects from has_many_and_belongs_to_many through 3 associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Models definition:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
  has_many :domains, :inverse_of=>:group
end

class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group, :inverse_of=>:domains
  has_many :pages, :inverse_of=>:domain
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :domain, :inverse_of=>:pages
  belongs_to :article, :inverse_of=>:pages
end
```

For specific `Article` I want to select all `Domains` (associated through `groups.domains`) without any `Page` associated with that `Article`.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups

  def avaiable_domains
    groups.domains("where not exists page with article_id=#{id}")) ##????
    #I have code mentioned at the end of this question, but I don't want use SQL, just pure active query
  end
end
```

Is it possible to write it in pure Active Record Query or Arel (without SQL in where method)?

For now I'm using this:

```
Domain.where(:group_id=>group_ids).where('NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pages WHERE pages.domain_id=domains.id AND article_id=?)',id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Domain.joins(:groups => :articles, :pages).where("pages.article_id <> :id AND articles.id = :id", id: article_id)
```

in domain model

```
   scope :available, ->(article_id){ joins(:groups => :articles,:pages).
          where("pages.article_id <> :id AND articles.id = :id", id: article_id)
```

in article model

```
  def available_domains
    Domain.available(id)
  end
```

Comment: ok. how you implement this in `avaiable_domains` method from question?

Comment: there is no association `:groups => :pages` id domain model

Comment: something like that) it will be a single query but i don't sure that it will perform faster